# Registering Style Hook in C++

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I am trying to register a style hook for a component that I have built using C++. But I am not sure how to get the `TClass` from my class definition. another word, how do I call `RegisterStyleHook` in C++. For example my component is called `TProgressBarEx` and my Style hook is `TProgressBarExStyleHook`. But 
    `TCustomStyleEngine::RegisterStyleHook(TProgressBarEx, TProgressBarExStyleHook);` does not compile because I need to get a `TClass` from `TProgressBarEx` and a `TStyleHookClass` from `TProgressBarExStyleHook`.

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 3):

I found the Answer myself. `TStyleHookClass` is just a `typedef` for `TClass` and **`__classid`** returns a **`TClass`** for any class definition. So my call should be like:
`TCustomStyleEngine::RegisterStyleHook(__classid(TProgressBarEx), __classid(TProgressBarExStyleHook));`